# IText pdf reader throwing exception "IndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I am using IText pdf reader to read pdf file but for few of the pdf file I am getting "**IndexOutOfBoundsException**".

below is the code

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader(file.getPath());
```

Exception I am getting : **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 9854** but can able to open the pdf file with other applications.

I tried with stream as well but getting same error.

Suggest how I can fix the issue.

Comment: Most likely there is an error in the PDF you're trying to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon all the try I found out the issue of getting exception. It is because of the iText API bug in its **version 5.1** and when I rebuilt my application with the latest **version 5.5.x.x** I get no exception and every thing works fine :)

Getting Answer From:

> [how to get out of String index out of range: -1 in iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802145/how-to-get-out-of-string-index-out-of-range-1-in-itext)

Comment: Version 5.2 by far is not the latest iText version. Currently iText is at version 8.x, and even if you need a version 5, there already is 5.5.x.

Comment: okey, use the 5.5.13.3 version. i think problem will be solved. I was facing the same problem then use this version